# Calculate Loss on Tensorflow CIFAR10 Multi GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In the TensorFlow CIFAR10 example

```
# Build the portion of the Graph calculating the losses. Note that we will
# assemble the total_loss using a custom function below.
_ = cifar10.loss(logits, labels)

# Assemble all of the losses for the current tower only.
losses = tf.get_collection('losses', scope)

# Calculate the total loss for the current tower.
total_loss = tf.add_n(losses, name='total_loss')

# Attach a scalar summary to all individual losses and the total loss; do the
# same for the averaged version of the losses.
for l in losses + [total_loss]:
    # Remove 'tower_[0-9]/' from the name in case this is a multi-GPU training
    # session. This helps the clarity of presentation on tensorboard.
    loss_name = re.sub('%s_[0-9]*/' % cifar10.TOWER_NAME, '', l.op.name)
    tf.contrib.deprecated.scalar_summary(loss_name, l)

return total_loss
```

Why the loss that returned by the function cifar10.loss is not used ? Instead the losses are calculated by tf.get_collection('losses', scope).

Answer (score 0):

The code returns the total loss for all the batches so far in a tower(single GPU). I think this is because they aren't interested in storing loss for a single batch but storing the total loss across all batches.

tf.get_collection retrieves all the losses for a tower using the scope of the tower. We can then use this to calculate avg loss across all batches in a tower or across both towers.